# Elixir Phoenix - Tracking Down Connection Reset by Peer Error

Tags: nginx, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm running a very highly concurrent Phoenix app and I am noticing that for around 10% of requests I am getting an `readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream` error in my nginx error files. I've added a log statement to the beginning of my first plug to print the incoming requests, but I am not seeing the requests arriving. I can't figure out why I am getting this error and how to debug it.

Attached is a copy of my nginx config file:

```
worker_processes 4;
user nginx nginx;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex on; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
}

http {
  include mime.types;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
  gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml application/json;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_buffers 8 64k;
  proxy_buffer_size 128k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

  upstream nolen {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name _;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

      location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
      }

      location @proxy {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://nolen;
      }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/selfsigned.key;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!ADH:!DH:!EDH:!CAMELLIA:!KRB5:!IDEA:!EXP:!eNULL:!LOW:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl.error.log;

    location / {
      try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://nolen;
    }
  }

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cloudflare.conf;
}
```

I am noticing the bug for both urls that take varying query parameters, as well as the serving of static js files which can be confirmed to be working normally.

Can anyone help guide me through the process of debugging this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen only when the server is under heavy load or is this reproducible on an idle server as well? Do these requests have a very long query string in them? Do a random 10% of the requests fail or do the requests that fail have something in common?

Comment: This happens under normal load conditions. We have added print statements at the very beginning of the endpoint.ex and are never seeing those connections. What is the first point in a Phoenix app where I can view all connections coming in. Printing the full url request would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

This normally results from a loss of the connection on the remote socket due to a timeout. For your testing you can try to ping for checking status before you send request, that why you be able to isolate the 10%